# How to get LINQ to SQL query to work with 'IN' and with wildcard scenario

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm trying to get a somewhat basic LINQ query but can't figure out all conditions.  yrs could equal several years like "2009,2008,2007" or is could equal "%", for a wildcard.  This query works for "2009,2008,2007" but does not work for the wildcard. How can I make it work for both conditions?

```
var results = (from a in db.t_harvest_statistics
                       where yrs.Contains(a.year) 
                       orderby a.id
                       select new { a.id, a.year, a.unit_number }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var results = (from a in db.t_harvest_statistics
                       where yrs.Contains(a.year) || yrs == "%"
                       orderby a.id
                       select new { a.id, a.year, a.unit_number }).ToList();
```

Comment: Well sometimes it will have values and sometimes it will be wildcarded. Wouldn't that script always wildcard the results for yrs?

Comment: In this case % isn't being evaluated as a wildcard by the SQL engine or the code.  Its a simple string comparison that evalates to true if yrs == "%".  This should work for you.

Comment: well the second condition is just checking to see if `yrs` is equal to the string `%`.  It's not using the same logic as a sql `like` statement.

Comment: Ah...ok. I just ran and test and it works.  Thanks for your help.